# How to merge two vertices into one?

Tags: vertices

In the screenshot you can see I have two vertices selected. How can I make them one, and consequently (hopefully) close the gaps in my model?

[image]

**EDIT**: After I did `m` `a` as suggested by Martynas and dissolved vertices.. i got what I wanted :D

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit <kbd>m</kbd> -> <kbd>a</kbd> while in edit mode to call Merge menu and choose At Center option from it.

[image]

You can also reach it from the Mesh menu:

[image]

That might not be the fastest or most convenient way, however that menu has all these other options that you might be interested to see.

Also you could just hit <kbd>F3</kbd> and start typing whatever you wavt to do and if you guess the name of the operation, it's going to show up there:

[image]

Comment: You are right! It did work. Thanks a lot. I managed to fill the gaps after dissolving vertices :) Updated question with screenshots

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding screenshots and all! I will accept in when possible (3 minutes)

Comment: I was going to just write m->a,  but BSE does not let short answers like that, apparently, there is a minimum character limit. :D

Comment: The Merge menu merges two verts into one so dissolving isn't necessary.